# MySQL Common price from previous 10 days vs current price - MySQL Performance Improvement

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, sql-execution-plan

I am casually building a website using phpMyAdmin and have created the below SQL code to get the most frequent price from the previous 10 days and compare it to the current price to identify price drops. The problem I have however is that it takes ~10 seconds to run due to the amount of products and prices. I am looking for ways to improve the query to reduce the webpage load time.

I have three tables products, product_categories, prices. product_categories is what I am filtering the data on. Table structures are below however excluding some irrelevant columns:

prices table:

- sku | product_price | price_date | retailer

product_category table:

- product_type |category_1 | category_2 |category_3

products table:

- product_type | sku | retailer | product_name

[Execution Plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCWQk.png)

```
SELECT currentPrice as 'prodprice', meanPrice, priceDiff, prodDetails.sku, prodDetails.product_name, prodDetails.img FROM (
      SELECT products.sku, products.product_name, products.img, products.product_type, products.retailer, category_1, category_2, category_3 FROM products INNER JOIN product_categories on product_categories.product_type = products.product_type
      WHERE category_3 = 'Laptops') as prodDetails INNER JOIN (
      SELECT prices.product_price as 'currentPrice', prices.sku, prices.retailer, meanPrice, (prices.product_price/meanPrice)-1 as 'priceDiff' FROM prices RIGHT JOIN(
      SELECT MaxCountSub.sku, CountSub.product_price as 'meanPrice', CountSub.retailer
      FROM (SELECT prices.sku, prices.product_price, retailer, Count(prices.product_price) AS CountOfValue
            FROM prices
            WHERE price_date > CURRENT_DATE-10
            GROUP BY prices.sku, prices.product_price) As CountSub
            INNER JOIN 
          (SELECT dT.sku, Max(CountOfValue) As MaxCountOfValue, dT.retailer
            FROM
                (SELECT prices.sku, prices.product_price, retailer, Count(prices.product_price) AS CountOfValue
                  FROM prices WHERE price_date > CURRENT_DATE-10 GROUP BY prices.sku, prices.product_price) As dT
                  GROUP BY dT.sku) As MaxCountSub
            ON CountSub.sku = MaxCountSub.sku 
            AND CountSub.CountOfValue = MaxCountSub.MaxCountOfValue
            AND MaxCountSub.retailer = CountSub.retailer) as b 
      on b.retailer = prices.retailer and b.sku = prices.sku
      WHERE prices.price_date = CURRENT_DATE ORDER BY priceDiff ASC ) c on c.retailer = prodDetails.retailer and c.sku = prodDetails.sku  
      ORDER BY `c`.`priceDiff`  ASC LIMIT 8
```

product table

```
+----------------+--------+----------+---------------+
|  product_type  |  sku   | retailer | product_name  |
+----------------+--------+----------+---------------+
| 2 in 1         | 475750 | J        | Dell Inspiron |
| 2 in 1 Devices | 324155 | H        | Lenovo Chrome |
| 2 in 1 Devices | 311148 | H        | HP Pavilion x |
| 2 in 1 Devices | 332274 | H        | HP Envy x360  |
| 2 in 1 Devices | 332261 | H        | Lenovo Ideapa |
| 2 in 1 Devices | 312084 | H        | HP Spectre x3 |
| Laptop         | 473661 | J        | Lenovo IdeaPa |
| Laptop         | 482998 | J        | Asus VivoBook |
| Laptops        | 331133 | H        | Acer Nitro 5  |
| Laptops        | 336095 | H        | Lenovo Ideapa |
| Laptops        | 326802 | H        | Predator Heli |
| Laptops        | 326712 | H        | Acer Nitro 5  |
| Laptops        | 326601 | H        | Acer Nitro 5  |
| Laptops        | 326589 | H        | Predator Trit |
| Laptops        | 336100 | H        | Lenovo Legion |
| Laptops        | 336101 | H        | Lenovo Legion |
| Laptops        | 311527 | H        | Acer Swift 5  |
| Laptops        | 295323 | H        | HP 14-inch Ce |
| Laptops        | 332257 | H        | Lenovo Ideapa |
| Laptops        | 327328 | H        | Acer Aspire 5 |
+----------------+--------+----------+---------------+
```

prices table

```
+--------+---------------+------------+----------+
|  sku   | product_price | price_date | retailer |
+--------+---------------+------------+----------+
| 295323 |           358 | 20/09/2020 | H        |
| 295323 |           358 | 21/09/2020 | H        |
| 295323 |           448 | 22/09/2020 | H        |
| 311148 |          1088 | 20/09/2020 | H        |
| 311148 |          1088 | 21/09/2020 | H        |
| 311148 |          1399 | 22/09/2020 | H        |
| 311527 |          1099 | 20/09/2020 | H        |
| 311527 |          1099 | 21/09/2020 | H        |
| 311527 |          1799 | 22/09/2020 | H        |
| 312084 |          1688 | 20/09/2020 | H        |
| 312084 |          1688 | 21/09/2020 | H        |
| 312084 |          1999 | 22/09/2020 | H        |
| 326712 |          1899 | 20/09/2020 | H        |
| 326712 |          1899 | 21/09/2020 | H        |
| 326712 |          2399 | 22/09/2020 | H        |
| 327328 |          1098 | 20/09/2020 | H        |
| 327328 |          1098 | 21/09/2020 | H        |
| 327328 |          1399 | 22/09/2020 | H        |
| 332261 |           999 | 20/09/2020 | H        |
| 332261 |           999 | 21/09/2020 | H        |
| 332261 |          1199 | 22/09/2020 | H        |
| 332274 |          1799 | 20/09/2020 | H        |
| 332274 |          1799 | 21/09/2020 | H        |
| 332274 |          2199 | 22/09/2020 | H        |
| 336095 |          1349 | 20/09/2020 | H        |
| 336095 |          1349 | 21/09/2020 | H        |
| 336095 |          1799 | 22/09/2020 | H        |
| 482998 |         763.3 | 20/09/2020 | J        |
| 482998 |         763.3 | 21/09/2020 | J        |
| 482998 |         763.3 | 22/09/2020 | J        |
+--------+---------------+------------+----------+
```

product category table

```
+----------------+-------------+------------+------------+
|  product_type  | category_1  | category_2 | category_3 |
+----------------+-------------+------------+------------+
| 2 in 1         | Electronics | Computers  | Laptops    |
| 2 in 1 Devices | Electronics | Computers  | Laptops    |
| Chromebook     | Electronics | Computers  | Laptops    |
| Laptop         | Electronics | Computers  | Laptops    |
| Laptops        | Electronics | Computers  | Laptops    |
| MacBook Air    | Electronics | Computers  | Laptops    |
| MacBook Pro    | Electronics | Computers  | Laptops    |
| Netbook        | Electronics | Computers  | Laptops    |
| Ultrabook      | Electronics | Computers  | Laptops    |
| 2 in 1 Laptops | Electronics | Computers  | Laptops    |
+----------------+-------------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: Please share your execution plan.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and your query is invalid standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.  Your query also has little to do with your question, so it is unclear what you really want to accomplish.

Comment: I have attached additional information. I'm hoping it answers the questions. I am also just using wamp/phpmyadmin which I believe is mysql.

Comment: What version of MySQL?  8.0 has windowing functions.

Comment: Could you provide about 20 rows from the relevant tables _in text, not images_ ?  That way, we could experiment on your data and query.

Comment: I believe it is version 5.7.21

Comment: @El.Hum - I have included the execution plan in the post